# Passing variable to route config

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Need some help, i just want to make simple task: pass variable from app.component.ts to app.module.ts in routes.

In app.component.ts i am getting some value from service like:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.subsc = this.someService.someMethod().subscribe(
      (someId: any[]) => {
        console.log(someId);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("some error");
      }
    ); 
  }
```

I am trying to get this someId and pass it to app.module.ts like:

```
const pmRoutes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', redirectTo: someId+'/some-other-component', pathMatch: 'full' }     
];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you describe. In Angular, you need to create routes that match a given pattern. If you need an id, then this is the approach you must have:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '{someId}/some-other-component', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Then you handle the value of `someId` in the component. For example, say that you want to navigate to that path when the user clicks a button. Then, on the `(click)` method you'd have:

```
constructor(protected router: Router) {}

onClick(id) {
    this.router.navigate([id, 'some-other-component']);
}
```

Angular will then see that this route matches the one you've provided and load the corresponding component.

**EDIT**

This is how the guard should look like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { ServiceToFetchTheRouteValue } from 'somewhere';

@Injectable() export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private service: ServiceToFetchTheRouteValue) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
        // assuming you get your value asynchronously and getValue() returns an Observable
        return this.service.getValue().map((value: any) => {
            // + is to convert the value to number;
            return value === +route.params['someId'];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But actually this will not work for me, because i want to default route be something like: 127.0.0.1/somevalue and this value is coming from service on load not on click, thats i am trying to do.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use the solution above along with a guard that will check if the `someId` value is equal to the one provided by your API. Something like:
`{ path: '', redirectTo: '{someId}/some-other-component', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: CheckValueGuard }`

Comment: Yeap, i tried with canActivate but i got lost : ( could you please give me example?

Comment: I have provided an example of how you could use the guard in the initial answer. Check that out and if you have any more questions, please let me know. :)